# Why can't I get the exact element I'm hovering over?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Let me start off by saying I'm no jQuery expert. However, I have code (included below) that will grab the element I hover over. The problem I have is if I have the following structure, inside my `<div id="literalContent">`:

```
<div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div>
```

And I hover over the final `<div>`, I see the border and That's awesome. However, if I then want to select the parent table, it is not selected. Any thoughts on my silly problem would be great.

```
 $(function () {
        $('#literalContent').find("*").hover(
            function () {

                $('[class="SelectedItem"]').removeAttr("class");
                $(this).fadeIn(500, function () {
                    $(this).addClass("SelectedItem");
                })
                //$(this).addClass("SelectedItem");
                //$('#controllabel').html('hovering ' + $(this).prop("tagName"));
            },
            function () {
                if ($(this).attr('class') == "SelectedItem") {
                    $(this).removeAttr("class");
                }
                else {
                    $(this).removeClass("SelectedItem");
                }
            });
    }
    );
```

Comment: I don't see any attempt to access the table in your code...

Comment: which `div` in your HTML sample has the id of `literalContent`?

Comment: please attach html or fiddle.

Comment: @orzechowskid, all of this would be inside the `<div id="literalContent>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To highlight only the target (and not any of its ancestors), you can toggle a class on the target's immediate parent on mouseenter/mouseleave.

http://jsfiddle.net/kU3Ba/1/

```
$('#outer').find('*').hover(

function (e) {
    var o = $(e.currentTarget),
        par = o.parent();

    o.addClass('redBorder');

    if(par[0].id != "outer"){ // exclude "outer", since it is the wrapper

        par.addClass('hideBorder'); // parent still has "redBorder" class
                                    // "hideBorder" just hides it
    }

    console.log(e.currentTarget.id+" has focus");
},

function (e) {
    var o = $(e.currentTarget),
        par = o.parent();

    o.removeClass('redBorder');
    par.removeClass('hideBorder');

    if(par[0].id != "outer"){ // exclude "outer", since it is the wrapper
        console.log(par[0].id+" has focus");
    }

});
```

This will visibly hide the border of immediate parent, and "return" the border once the mouse leaves its child.

Comment: That worked, kind of what @jay-blanchard and I were talking about but this works exactly... now if only I can get the text to stop bouncing around when the boarder is added...

Comment: @Ucf_Falcon Borders add to the element's width and height, offsetting the surrounding elements. You can counter act that by decreasing the element's padding by as many pixels as the border increases; or you can explore using alternative CSS properties such as `outline`, or `box-shadow` which take up no additional space.

Comment: Man awesome... Thanks so much, box-shadow worked great, I hadn't even though of it!

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be working here - http://jsfiddle.net/jayblanchard/ucM96/

```
$('#outer').find('*').hover(

function () {
    $(this).addClass('redBorder');
},

function () {
    $(this).removeClass('redBorder');
});
```

Note that selecting inner4 with the mouse causes the hover to be applied to inner3 as well - due to their relationship and how mouse events are handled.

You can be more specific by doing something like giving multiple selectors -

```
$('.foo, .bar').hover(

function (e) {
    $(this).addClass('redBorder');
    console.log(e.target.id);
},

function () {
    $(this).removeClass('redBorder');
});
```

Comment: Right so your second code illustrates my initial problem.. if I select the blue square, then the parent has to be selected also which doesn't work when i have like 30-40 nested tags it gets super messy quick

Comment: If you're performing deep nesting and need to get at those layers with a hover you're better off specifying the hoverable items via classes or id's. Check out my edit above http://jsfiddle.net/jayblanchard/ucM96/3/

Comment: Yeah I wish I could however this is going to be based on user input. in essence what I'm trying to accomplish here is what firebug or chrome developer tools does when you inspect an element. 

Based on User input allow a user to hover over and see each element individually

Comment: I'll have to think on it for a bit, but I'm sure that there is a way to return info from complex nesting. Most inspectors do select the ancestors though - that is how they create the breadcrumb for each item.

Comment: Hmm so perhaps the answer is to set a "noboarder" class on the ancestors and a different class on the selected item?

Comment: Should be easy to test.